# How information can be lost by reading and writing files in Python?

Tags: python, sql, file, input, output

I have an `.sql` file. I use Python to read it line by line and save each line in another file. So, in theory the input and output files have to be the same but in fact the output file is more than 10 times smaller than the input one. This is how i do it:

```
f = open('output.txt','w')
for line in file('input.sql'):
    line = line.replace('\n','')
    print >>f, line
f.close()
```

Does anybody know at what stage the information is lost and why?

Comment: @joelgoldstick, why do you think that my *.sql file is an sqlite file?

Comment: have you examined the content of both files and saw any differences? And I  cannot reproduce the issue with your code

Comment: @LeiShi, I cannot open the *.sql file in a text editor because it is about 2G in size. The *.txt file is about 150M in size. I open it with text editors and see there some SQL statements and my data. The number of rows in the *.txt file seems to be OK.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue :( And, the code looks so simple that there could "hardly" be any misuses.  Another try you might do is to peak the head & tail of input.sql, and compare them with the corresponding parts in output.txt, to see whether you can find anything wrong.  If you're on linux bash, commands "head" and "tail" can be used.

Comment: Did you find out any cause?

Answer (score 0):

There are some inherent differences between a dos file and a unix file.

One such difference is the presence of ^M character in dos file, which is not present in unix file.

You can see these special characters in your file by running a `cat -a` or `cat -steve` command, if you are using a Linux machine.

For e.g, the statement `Hi there` is `Hi there^M$` when analyzed with cat -steve for dos format (file was created in, say, windows OS), and `Hi there$` in unix format.

Try running `cat -steve <filename>`

If your input file was a dos file, and you are processing the output in linux machine, there are chances the output is linux formatted. Naturally, unix files are more compact than dos files.

Edit : You can get rid of, or enforce ^M characters in your file by running `dos2unix <file_name>` , or `unix2dos <file_name>`.